# Send push notification for chat app build using Firebase Realtime Database

Tags: ios, firebase, push-notification, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

Im currently using **Firebase Realtime Database** to build an chat application. I took [this Raywenderlich tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/140836/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat-2)   as my starting point to learn Firebase.

In My case i need to send push notification when there is a new message ( also push notification for other **Database changes in Firebase**).
I know there is FCM and Firebase Notification to send push notification, but they can only be triggered externally from and HTTP request.

I don't mind having my own Node.js server to achieve this, but how do i do this?
How do i track where there is a new message (Change in DB ).

And what is Firebase Admin SDK ? should I be using that?
Im new to Firebase and kinda lost. Can someone put me on track ?

Comment: Recommended reading: https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/08/sending-notifications-between-android.html

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks for the blog. it was useful

Comment: Do you find any easy solution over it? If, you know any idea, please let me know. I want to implement the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I asked this question Google did not have the `Firebase cloud functions`. In case anyone stumbles upon this question, I finally ended up solving this problem using Cloud Functions (still in beta).

[Cloud Functions for Notifications use case](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Firebase Cloud Functions to do this.

1. The function triggers on writes to the Realtime Database "/notifications/{uid}/something".
2. The function composes a message to send via FCM.
3. FCM sends the notification message to the user's device.

Have a look at this tutorial [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) to find out how to create an function trigger.

If you need to know how to send notification messages have a look at this tutorial [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/fcm-notifications).

Answer (score 0):

You are right, you should do it using an admin server.

@AM_ answer is a good start : you will need a background task that listens for data changes. But there is now better ways to do it.

[Firebase has a queue system](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/05/introducing-firebase-queue_97.html), that allows you to create multiple workers to handle background jobs.
Here is an exemple implementation : https://github.com/mcdonamp/sanichat

And instead of directly building an http POST request to use FCM, the [Firebase Admin Node.Js SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/admin/send-messages) does provide an API for FCM. Java version does not yet.

Finally, here is a [nice Firebase team blog post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/11/bringing-firebase-to-your-server.html) about Admin SDK.